# "Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions." Latest versions of Babel/core and Babel-loader

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs, upgrade

So I have the latest versions of Babel/core and Babal-loader installed, because I'm trying to upgrade to Webpack 4, but it says:

```
Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.
```

When I run Webpack in dev mode. I can't really downgrade because then Webpack 4 won't work. Here are my dev dependencies:

```
devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-es2015": "^7.0.0-beta.53",
    "acorn": "^6.1.1",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.2",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "6.22.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.3.1",
    "bootstrap-loader": "3.0.4",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "3.14.1",
    "eslint-config-standard": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "2.0.7",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "2.0.1",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "express": "4.14.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "0.10.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
    "function-bind": "1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.3",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "opn": "4.0.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "ora": "1.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "postcss-input-range": "github:whatknight/postcss-input-range#bugfix",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "2.0.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.0",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "semver": "6.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.14.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "15.7.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "2.3.3",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.6.2",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.24.4",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.1"
  },
```

And here's my babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["stage-2", "@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "comments": false
}
```

And here's the part where causes the issue:

```
{
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/vue-awesome'), resolve('node_modules/vue-uploader')],
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['stage-2', '@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }


      },
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The `'stage-2'` preset is for Babel 6. Since you're on Babel 7, that will fail. The stage presets were removed in Babel 7 entirely (https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets). You should install the specific proposal plugins that you actually want to use.